# Are logs of FirebaseAnalytics batched?

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to know when we call

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent(name, parmas);
```

is the logged event sent over the network in realtime or are the logs batched and sent at periodic intervals?

I couldn't find any definitive answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Regular events are batched up indeed, and then written once an hour. But when you log a conversion event, the SDK tries to send that to the server right away - along with any other events that are pending.

Also see this (rather old, but still relevant) blog post [How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up), which contains more information about this.